# Date Parsing succeed in French but fails in English

Tags: java, parsing, date, datetime

Consider this program that format the current date, and try to parse it again. It succeeds in French, but fails in English and I don't understand why.

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

         try{
             SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
             DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT,DateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(formatter.format(new Date()));

             System.out.println("English - success");
         }catch(Exception ex){
             System.out.println(ex);
         }

         try{
             SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.FRENCH);

             DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT,DateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.FRENCH).parse(formatter.format(new Date()));
             System.out.println("French - success");

         }catch(Exception ex){
             System.out.println(ex);
         }
        System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
     }
}
```

Output:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11 Feb 2015 11:09:26"                                                                                                                           
French -success                                                                                                                                                                             
en_US
```

Please look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29 before telling me that I should use a pattern or anything else. This method is meant to parse a `String` without a pattern.

Comment: If you try to format a `Date` first with `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT,DateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.ENGLISH).format`, does it have the same style you're trying to parse? May be you find your error this way.

Comment: Are you surprised by the exception? You are formatting and then parsing with different formats. You were just lucky that the French default format fitted to the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your input format string is wrong.

As per [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#DEFAULT) `Jun 30, 2009 7:03:47 AM` would be a valid format for en_US on `Default` settings.

You could always check if your format is right by formatting a given `Date` first.
For example 
`System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT,DateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date()));` gives `Feb 11, 2015 12:34:48 PM`, which doesn't fit `11 Feb 2015 11:09:26`.

This should be your correct formatted string for en_US parsing: `Feb 11, 2015 11:09:26 AM`. Remember, this is AM / PM 12 hour time format, which can be annoying.

Comment: The input format can be just anything. That's the purpose of this method. 

But I tried with "MMM, dd yyyy HH:mm:ss a" just like you suggest and it was not working either.

Comment: You only need one H to specifiy 12-hour format. Then it'll work. It is odd however that this method can't parse "dd MMM yyyy" in English but does it in French.

Comment: There is no heuristic to detect the input format, so it can't be anything. If it was, date parsing wouldn't be such a pain ;) You just use the default parameters, which are defined somewhere to reflect standards.

Comment: @Maxoudela It works for me. You also need to include AM into your string, otherwise the date can't be parsed. and also it is `MMM dd,` not `MMM, dd` as per your comment.

Comment: Guess you were right... I tried several other combination and I found Exception in both Locale.. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Just for the record, my colleague is using C# and they apparently have a method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ) that is really working whatever the input is.
Or course it cannot guess some case like "01 01 12" because it's impossible but "11 Feb 2015 11:09:26" is parsed correctly. And I found shocking that Java can't understand that because it's obvious that 11 refers to the day, Feb to the month and 2015 to the year....

Answer (score 0):

The default format for English is like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: It succeed in french. So this may not be the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I saw that. amended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss is a correct english format dont they use month before days like US format ?

Comment: I tried to use "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss" and it did not work. But I don't think it's the issue here..